# Search query doesn't work in solr/browse panel

Tags: solr

When I create a query like `something&fl=content` in solr/browse the "&" and "=" in URL converted to %26 and %3D and no result occurs.  How can I solve this problem?
Is it possible to change the request from the GET method to a POST?